# Вложенные таблицы

Tags: html, css

Все мои познания по хтмл ограничивались ещё в институте на 2-м курсе на лабах, и вот теперь уткнулся.
Суть такая: мне нужно сгенерировать документ для печати в Google Cloud Print из календаря.
Так выглядит в нативном приложении:   https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5581/15048360619_e7df0f013c_o.png
Я вижу такую реализацию - таблица в 5 строк и 7 таблица, где каждая ячейка - это день.

При этом день (ячейка), в свою очередь, отдельная таблица. Её я вижу как 5 строк и 2 столбца.
Где первый столбец - это событие. А второй - объединение по всем 5-ти строкам - дата.
Попробовал сделать каркас: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7q5lix2f20fr9oy/default2.htm?dl=0
Но что-то не так делаю.
Не могу задать, чтобы все строки/столбцы внещней таблицы имели одинаковую высоту/ширину.
Во внутренней таблице дата не выравнена по правому краю.

Comment: @Schumi, ваша первая ссылка вдает 404 ошибку. Без нее довольно затруднительно понять, что именно вы хотите сделать.

Comment: @DreamChild, поправил. Хотя в принципе уже разобрался :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ага, с постоянной шириной понятно:

```
td.main { 
        width: 14.2857143%;
        border: 1px solid gray; /* Граница вокруг ячеек */
}
```

С выравниванием даты к правому краю тоже понятно. У вложенной таблица тоже надо задать ширину в 100%.